# Cómo comparar los 2 tablas en distintas BD (oracle y Mysql) que muestre los valores que no coinciden

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, oracle, web

Estoy consultando ideas, tengo 2 base de datos diferentes (oracle y otra de mysql) en distintos servidores, la misma tienen tablas en común, necesito comprar los campos de ambas base de datos,
de ser posible implementar con un lenguaje de programación como php, o alguno que me recomienden... no tengo idea concreta del mismo

Comment: Estimado, bienvenido a StackOverflow, te recomiendo leer [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y editar tu pregunta ya que las preguntas basadas en opiniones por lo general son mal recibidas.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo recogiendo todas la tablas con `show tables;` y recorres con un bucle ese array donde haces la siguiente sql `show columns from $tuTabla;`.

Podrías generar un array de este estilo:

```
{'tabla1' : ['campo1', 'campo2'], 'tabla2': ['campo1', 'campo2', 'campo3']}
```

Obtienes los arrays de las dos bases y los comparas.

Puedes formatear tu array como quieras.

**Editado:**

Con este código obtienes un array como el que te he mostrado.

```
    $tables = "Show tables;"; //Obtenemos todas las tablas
    $arrTablas = $this->db->query($tables)->result_array();

    $result1 = array();
    foreach ($arrTablas as $arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) { //Las recorremos para obtener una a una
                    $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $value"; // Obtenemos todos los campos por tabla
                    $arrCampos = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
                    foreach ($arrCampos as $k => $v) {
                        $result1[$value][] = $v['Field']; //Guardamos un array donde la key es el nombre de tu tabla y el valor los campos
                    }
        }
    }
```

Deberas generar dos arrays. Uno por conexion a base de datos.

Cuando tengas los dos arrays. `$result1` y `$result2` los comparas con la función que dijiste, de esta manera. `array_diff_assoc($result1, $result2)`

Te paso información adicional sobre lo que hace esta función https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff-assoc.php

Comment: Buenos días, como le explico, tengo 2 query diferentes a la base de datos oracle ('SELECT id, dcs_code, vend_code,description,attr,siz,qty,store_no,cost FROM inventario ) el mismo select para mysql... necesito comprar estas dos consultas, busque ayuda pero no veo nada relacionado, leí sobre una tabla temporal de oracle en mysql pero no comprendo como crear la tabla para mantener las 2 en mysql, me indican que la comparación se hace desde php (array_diff_assoc) tengo muchas dudas

Comment: Hola! @RafaelPeña edite la respuesta con más información. Un saludo.